# How to output information in Visual Studio by assembler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I try to use assembler and when I call int 0x80 my program crash. What I should do if I want to output some information in console by assembler in my C++ code?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char *msg = "Hello";

    __asm
    {      
        mov eax, 4; 
        mov ebx, 1;
        mov ecx, msg; 
        mov edx, 5; 
        //int 0x80;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int 0x80` is the 32-bit *Linux* ABI for making system calls.  Use Windows DLL calls, or since this is *inline* asm, leave values in C++ variables and print them with `cout` or printf.  Or use a debugger to look at them instead of writing debug-print code.

Comment: Isn't there a similar command for windows as int 0x80?

Comment: Yes, for any specific version of the Windows kernel, there is a system-call ABI that the DLLs use.  But unlike Linux, it's not stable across kernel versions, and not documented by MS, only reverse engineered.  The only stable ABI is DLL function calls (like WinAPI and NT functions).  Presumably that's usable from MSVC's legacy 32-bit only inline asm if you really really want to.  [Windows system calls](//stackoverflow.com/q/21074334)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was found some intresting method to output Hello world in Inline ASM using Visual Studio C++.

```
char* hi = "Hello World\n";
char* text = "%s";
__asm
{
    mov eax, hi;             // load C pointer variable from memory
    push eax;                // function args on the stack with rightmost highest
    mov eax, text;
    push eax;
    call DWORD ptr printf;    // indirect call to DLL function
    pop eax;                  // clean up the stack
    pop eax;                  // with these 2 dummy pops
}
```

More about it is describe in this article: http://rodrigosavage.blogspot.com/2010/07/hello-world-with-inline-asm.html?m=1

Comment: Using `pop ebx` to clean up the stack forces the compiler to save/restore EBX in the function containing your asm.  Use `add esp,8` or 2x `pop eax`.  Or if you want to preserve the printf return value in EAX, use ECX or EDX as a dummy.

Comment: You don't need 2 almost-the-same code blocks, just remove the worse one.

Comment: You fixed one inefficiency but introduced another.  Fixed to be no worse than before.  Just using inline asm at all is inefficient for this so there's not much point worrying about it really.  (Look at the optimized compiler-generated asm for the whole function for this vs. a pure C function.)

Comment: Thank you. I just use it for my task in the university and no where else. And after that I don't use it uneffective construction. And also I'm a little interested in going into it.